# Не получается рекурсивно создать папки

Tags: python

Есть json-файл:

```
[{
  "name": "Moscow"
},
{
 "name": "Khabarovsk"
},
{
  "name": "Samara"
}]
```

Исходя из этих данных мне нужно рекурсивно создать папки:

```
/moscow
/moscow/khabarovsk
/moscow/samara
/khabarovsk
/khabarovsk/moscow
/khabarovsk/samara
/samara
/samara/moscow/
/samara/khabarovsk
```

Написал для этого следующий скрипт:

```
import sys, os, json, re, errno
from pprint import pprint

cities = json.load(open('routes.json'))

for city in cities:
    dir_single = city["name"].replace(' ', '-').lower()
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dir_single)):
        try:
            os.makedirs(dir_single)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
                print('Skipped: ' + dir_single)
            else:
                raise
        with open(dir_single + '/index.php', 'w') as f:
            f.write("<?php include('../generator.php'); ?>")

for city in cities:
    for city_nested in cities:
        dir = city["name"].replace(' ', '-').lower() + '/' + city_nested["name"].replace(' ', '-').lower()
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dir)):
            if city_nested["name"] != city["name"]:
                try:
                    os.makedirs(dir)
                except OSError as e:
                    if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
                        print('Skipped: ' + dir)
                    else:
                        raise
                with open(dir + '/index.php', 'w') as f:
                    f.write("<?php include('../../generator.php'); ?>")
```

Папки первого уровня(`/moscow/`, `/samara/` и `/khabarovsk/`) создаются нормально, а вот вложенные папки создаются неправильно. Внутри `/moscow/` создаётся папка `/leipzig/`, а внутри неё `/halle/`. Получается папка `/moscow/leipzig/halle/`, то есть совершенно не то, что мне нужно. Не могу понять, что не так?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему данную задачу можно решить проще и элегантнее.

Имея следующий список в качестве данных на входе:

```
In [114]: lst
Out[114]: [{'name': 'Moscow'}, {'name': 'Khabarovsk'}, {'name': 'Samara'}]
```

Решение:

```
import os
from itertools import permutations

cities = [d.get('name') for d in lst]

base_dir = '/'

[os.makedirs(os.path.join(base_dir, os.path.join(pair[0], pair[1])))
 for pair in permutations(cities, 2)]
```

Результат (на Windows для `base_dir = 'd:/temp/cities'`):

```
In [117]: for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir, topdown=False):
     ...:    for name in files:
     ...:       print(os.path.join(root, name))
     ...:    for name in dirs:
     ...:       print(os.path.join(root, name))
     ...:
d:/temp/cities\Khabarovsk\Moscow
d:/temp/cities\Khabarovsk\Samara
d:/temp/cities\Moscow\Khabarovsk
d:/temp/cities\Moscow\Samara
d:/temp/cities\Samara\Khabarovsk
d:/temp/cities\Samara\Moscow
d:/temp/cities\Khabarovsk
d:/temp/cities\Moscow
d:/temp/cities\Samara
```

Comment: Зачем использовать генератор списка там, где не требуется создание этого списка?

Comment: @mkkik, в данном случае наверное это неуместно. Постараюсь исправить когда доберусь до компьютера...

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. `os.path.dirname()` не умеет проверять вложенность и если в качестве аргумента предоставить этой функции `moscow/saint-petersburg`, то она вернёт просто `moscow`. Убрал это условие и всё заработало.

Comment: назначение `dirname()`, чтобы вернуть часть пути, относящуюся к директории. К примеру: `dirname('a/b/c') == 'a/b'`, `dirname('a/b/') == 'a/b'`, `dirname('a/b') == 'a'`, `dirname('a/') == 'a'`, `dirname('a') == ''`, `dirname('') == ''`